# In Vim's insert mode, how can you go to the end of the line and insert a newline?

Tags: vim, textmate

In TextMate, when you're not at the end of a line and you want to enter a newline, you can type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd>.

Is there an equivalent for this in Vim, when you're in insert mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> do? It's two keypresses, just like <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>, and you don't have to hold them at the same time.  The only drawback I can think of is that you temporarily leave insert mode.

Comment: Yes, that'll do just fine. I've seen people discuss mapping the Esc key in Vim to another key. I may look into that depending on pinkie fatigue.

Answer (score 5):

this should do the trick:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>

Comment: Just to clarify for folks, it appears your recommend is `Ctrl-o` followed by just `o`. Works brilliantly, especially with my Caps Lock and Control keys swapped, so as to reduce pinkie fatigue.

Comment: That's useful. I forgot `Ctrl-O` means "use normal mode for the next command!

Answer (score 1):

I was used to Home/End getting me to the start and end of lines in Insert mode (from use in Windows and I think Linux), which Mac doesn't support.  This is particularly annoying because when I'm using vim on a remote system, I also can't easily do it.  After some painful trial and error, I came up with these `.vimrc` lines which do the same thing, but bound to Ctrl-A for the start of the line and Ctrl-D for the end of the line.  (For some reason, Ctrl-E I guess is reserved or at least I couldn't figure a way to bind it.)  Enjoy.

```
:imap <Char-1> <Char-15>:normal 0<Char-13>
:imap <Char-4> <Char-15>:normal $<Char-13>
```

There's a good chart here for the ASCII control character codes here for others as well:

http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html

You can also do Ctrl-V + Ctrl- as well, but that doesn't paste as well to places like this.